# Short question: Does calculating the determinant change if in your matrices the entries aren't from $\Bbb{R}$?

Tags: matrices

For example if my matrix has entries of $\Bbb{Z}/5 \Bbb{Z}$?

Comment: So what im asking is, whether i can still use laplacess formula ? Or do i have to take care about something ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the formulas and methods for computing determinants are the same, no matter what field or ring the entries live in.